# How to save nested array of objects data using mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

So, I'm sending data from angular reactive form like:
[Angular reactive form UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOECd.png)

and 
[Data being sent to backend in browser console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeTWg.png)

I have made schema for task as:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let taskSchema = new Schema({
    taskId:{
        type:String,
        unique:true
    },
    task:{
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    subTask:[{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'SubTask'
    }]
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task',taskSchema);
```

Schema for Sub-Task as:

```
let subTaskSchema = new  Schema({
    title:String,
    subSubTask:[{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'SubSubTask'
    }]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('SubTask',subTaskSchema);
```

Schema  for Sub-Sub-Task as:

```
let subSubTaskSchema = new  Schema({
    title:String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('SubSubTask',subSubTaskSchema);
```

Now,I'm confused about how to save nested array of objects data in mongodb using mongoose?

Comment: i think you made error in this line not sure of it but please check 
`module.exports = mongoose.model('subTask',subTaskSchema);` 
it should be `module.exports = mongoose.model('SubTask',subTaskSchema);`
when you are using it to refer you using 'SubTask'

Comment: fixed this one,  I'm having trouble in polpulating it, its giving me empty subTask array

Comment: can you share the code via git or something?

Comment: https://github.com/sanjayadav/ToDoList/tree/master/app/controllers , open dashboardController and code is in createTask() -> taskCreationFunction() & subTaskCreationFunction()

Comment: I checked your code you are not creating a sub task first

Comment: suggested order: create task > create subtask & add to task

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually the problem was in data which was sent by angular, I had to stringify data before sending and parsed it after receiving on backend, then proceeded with steps above and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your schema like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    likedBooks: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'books'
    }],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

exports.User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

then you can populate data by doing

```
user = User.find({ email: req.body.email }).populate('likedBooks');
```

here likedBooks contains _id of each book

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isbn: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    publisher: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
});

exports.Book = mongoose.model('books', bookSchema);
```

for both schema i have not put _id as it is auto generated by mongodb and it is used as reference

Comment: Hey, could you please share books schema as well?

Comment: @SanjayYadav i have eddited my answer please check

Comment: Thanks for sharing the schema, I've updated my schema, now there are 3 schema in total for my data, I've edited the question, please check if schema are correct.

Comment: Also, please help me in proceeding to next step, I'm stuck on this issue from last 2 days.

Comment: all the documents will have _id which will be auto generated by mongo db, store this _id of subTask in subtask array of task

Answer (score 0):

The Object Model should look like this before saving.

`{
    taskId: 1,
    task: 'Do something',
    subTask: [{
        title: 'Write a essay',
        subSubTask: [{
            title: 'Collect details to write an essay'
        }]
    }]
}`

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for replying but actually it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm sending all the data from angular service through parameters, so I'm using req.body for eg. { task : req.body.task } but how do I do it for array of objects in my question above?

Comment: Are you facing problem in sending the values to server? Or is there any problem while you are trying to save the value using mongoose?

Comment: There's an error when I'm trying to save values using mongoose, How do I save nested array of objects using mongoose?

Comment: You don't need to do anything specific just a usual save. Can you provide your here? So we can analyse it quickly.